# Python find the coordinates of black square on JPEG image

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have this sample image that has **white rectangular box with a single black square in it**. (2 blue arrows are just for illustration purpose, they are not part of the image)

[image]

Is there anyway to find out how many pixels is the black square away from the left and top boundaries of the image?

If possible, i prefer not to use `OpenCV` as the rest of the processing were done in `PIL` and it's probably an overkill if i have to use `OpenCV` just to do this one operation.

FYI: the image is in JPEG, there will always be only 1 black squre (no multiple squares) in the box.

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer by karlphillip, i have come up with this piece of code.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('test.png').convert('1')
pixels = img.load()

xlist = []
ylist = []
for y in xrange(img.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(img.size[0]):
        if pixels[x, y] == 0:
            xlist.append(x)
            ylist.append(y)

#4 corners of the black square
xleft = min(xlist)
xright = max(xlist)
ytop = min(ylist)
ybot = max(ylist)
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You might find [this thread valuable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1109422/176769).

Comment: @karlphillip care to elaborate a bit more? I thought `getdata()` will only give me a sequence of pixels of the contents of image. But still, how do i get the coordinates i want from that list anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1109422/176769) I mentioned, I was able to put together the following pseudocode:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('test.png')
pixels = img.load()

for y in xrange(img.size[1]):
    for x in xrange(img.size[0]):
        if pixels[x, y] == (0, 0, 0):
            // black pixel found, add it to a counter variable or something.
```

This answer demonstrates how to access and test each pixel in the image using PIL.