# Using train_test_split with images from my local directory

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have read the images from my local directory as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

root = '/Users/xyz/Desktop/data'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        img_path = os.path.join(path,name)
```

I have two subdirectories: `category-1` and `category-2`, each of which contains image files (.jpg) that belong to each category.

How can I use those images and two categories with the [train_test_split()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) function in Scikit-Learn? In other words, to arrange the training and testing data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to read pixel data from images and store it in a Pandas DataFrame or a numpy array. At the same time, you have to store corresponding category values `category-1 (1)` and `category-2 (2)` in a list or numpy array. Here is a rought sketch: I am going to assume that you have some store `categories` that returns `1` or `2` based on image name.

```
X = numpy.array([])
y = list()

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
  for name in files:
    img_path = os.path.join(path,name)
    correct_cat = categories[img_path]
    img_pixels = list(Image.open(img_path).getdata())
    X = numpy.vstack((X, img_pixels))
    y.append(correct_cat)
```

You are effectively storing image pixels and category values (converted to integers). There could be alternative ways of doing that: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109422/getting-list-of-pixel-values-from-pil) for example.

Once you have `X` and `y` lists, you can call `train_test_split` on them

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Comment: Nice. X can be a list. use np.array(X) to have a numpy array.