# Extracting pixel values using Pillow - every coordinate I use gives the same value

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing, pixel, python-imaging-library

I am attempting to use the Pillow library in Python 2.7 to extract pixel values at given coordinates on PNG and JPG images. I don't get an errors but I always get the same value irrespective of the coordinates I have used on an image where the values do vary.

This is an extract from my script where I print all the values (its a small test image):

```
from PIL import Image

box = Image.open("col_grad.jpg")

pixels = list(box.getdata())

print(pixels)
```

And from when I try to extract a single value:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

box = Image.open("col_grad.jpg")

value = box.load()

print(value[10,10])
```

I have been using these previous questions on this topic for guidance including:

[Getting list of pixel values from PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109422/getting-list-of-pixel-values-from-pil)

[How can I read the RGB value of a given pixel in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138250/how-can-i-read-the-rgb-value-of-a-given-pixel-in-python)

Thanks for any help with this,

Alex

Comment: can you upload the test image you've used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider doing one of the following:

**FIRST** convert your image to grayscale and then find the pixel values present.

```
img_grey= img.convert('1')     # convert image to black and white
```

**SECOND** If you want the pixel values of RGB channels, you have to split your color image. Then find the pixel values in all the channels at a particular coordinate.

```
Image.split(img)
```

Comment: Thanks. This has actually solved this issue for me as the analysis I am doing works better on a grayscale image.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can access it the way you want, because of the complexity of images data.

Just get [the pixel](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel):

> Image.getpixel(xy)
>
> ```
> Returns the pixel value at a given position.
> Parameters:   xy – The coordinate, given as (x, y).
> Returns:  The pixel value. If the image is a multi-layer image, this method returns a tuple.:
> ```