# How to get a matrix consisting of arrays of pixels and RGB?

Tags: python, matrix, rgb, pixel

I tried using the PIL library to get a matrix consisting of arrays of pixels and RGB, however, I only get a one-dimensional array and I don’t understand how to form a matrix of them

```
img = Image.open("E:\\1f9114.png").convert('RGB')
obj = img.load()
width, height = img.size 
for j in range(height):        
    for i in range(width):             
        matrix1=[i,j,obj[i,j]]            
        print(matrix1)           
    print()
```

I know that the matrix can turn out huge, and the usual sheet does not cope .I hope somebody will help, as it is important for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code snippet:

- `matrix1` is always overridden. If you want to add pixels to an existing list, use [`list.append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).
- [`im.getdata()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) should be used to obtain a one-dimensional raw pixel list from the image.

Here is an example (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109747/1584915)) to load pixels into a two-dimensional array that contains (r,g,b) tuples built using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and slices.

```py
pixels = list(img.getdata())
matrix1 = [pixels[i*width:(i+1)*width] for i in range(height)]
```